# If a group has more than one subgroup of order 5, it must have order of at least 25.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let, $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $|H| = |K| = 5$. From Lagrange's theorem, we know that $|H|$ and $|K|$ must divide $|G|$. Why can $|G|$ not be $10, 15$ or $20$? Why must it be at least $25$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the Sylow theorems?

Comment: Hint: $H$ and $K$ must both be cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for Sylow. Let $G, H$ be two distinct subgroups of order $5$. Then $G\cap H = \{1\}$, because $\{1\}$ is the only proper subgroup of any group of order $5$ (by Lagrange).

Now we show that $GH=\{gh\mid g\in G, h\in H\}$ has exactly $25$ elements. To show this, it's enough to show if $g_1h_1=g_2h_2$, then $g_1=g_2$ and $h_1=h_2$ for any $g_1, g_2\in G, h_1, h_2\in H$. Indeed, if $g_1h_1=g_2h_2$, then $g_2^{-1}g_1= h_2h_1^{-1}\in G\cap H$, therefore $g_2^{-1}g_1=h_2h_1^{-1}=1$.

The same argument works if $5$ is replaced by any prime number $p$.

Answer (score 1):

If a $5$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ has order at least $25$, then you're done.

If not, you know that $G$ has at least two $5$-Sylow subgroups.  In that case, what's the smallest number of $5$-Sylow subgroups $n_5$ that $G$ can have?  What do you know about the relationship between $n_5$ and $G$?  What conclusion can you reach about the order of $G$?

Comment: More like a series of questions than an answer.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus It's intended to be a very specific road map that leaves a little work for the original poster to do.